# Understanding the difference between local and global IPv6 address

Tags: delphi, ipv6

I'm implementing REST client in my Delphi application. The devices, I will be connecting to can be on local or global IPv6 addresses. The devices are having REST server and my application prepares REST URI by using %interface_index at the end of IPv6 address.
I'm observing connection problems when I use interface index(Zone_id) in the ipv6 address when its global.
I'm wondering if there is a way where i can differentiate between these and decide when to use the index or not.

Answer (score 1):

IANA maintains some documents that may help. For example, *[Internet Protocol Version 6 Address Space](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml)*

Every IPv6 interface will have a Link-Local address. Packets addressed with Link-Local addresses cannot be routed off the link (hence, Link-Local). Every link will use the same network, so you need to distinguish Link-Local addresses by adding a Zone ID. All Link-Local addresses are in the `fe80::/10` network.

Global addresses are in the `2000::/3` range, but there are some address blocks within that range that are not forwardable or globally reachable. See the *[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)*.

You should also study *[RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291)*.